# How to write a bug-free code when a pointer is associated?

Tags: c++, pointers

For example

```
struct A
{
    void foo() {};
};

struct B
{
    B() {}

    void setA(A* a) { mA = a; }
    foo()           { mA->foo(); }

    A *mA;
};
```

There is an `A` associated (just an address) within `B`. And `B::mA` must not be `null`. I usually forget to `setA` and bugs are introduced. What good practice to avoid it? And how about `setA` as following?

```
void B::setA(A& a) { mA = &a; }
```

Comment: Is `A` always created before `B`?

Comment: *What good practice to avoid [bugs]?* Don't make mistakes.

Comment: "How to write a bug-free code when a pointer is associated?" - carefully.

Comment: I nearly always check for null before using a pointer and then either assert or log the critical error if a pointer is null that should never be null. That combined with unit testing makes it easier to spot these kinds of errors.

Comment: @billz Yes, I can make sure `A` is always created before `B`.

Comment: Don't use naked pointers in public, or in private across more than one class.

Comment: @KerrekSB What does it mean in public and private across?

Comment: @user1899020: I meant "in private, across multiple classes". Don't let one class handle private naked pointers from inside another class. Basically, "single responsibility" and all that. That's the only principle that can keep you from combinatorial explosion of understanding who's responsible for what.

Comment: @KerrekSB I suppose by "naked pointers", you mean raw pointers.  Do you have some alternatives for navigation?  (None of the standard smart pointers are appropriate here.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: References, reference wrappers, nested classes (make the entire class private?), unique pointers... it depends. Raw pointers are semantic poison and should be kept to as small a scope as possible, as a general rule.

Comment: @KerrekSB So what's your alternative for navigation.  I'd guess that over 90% of my pointers are raw pointers, because I've yet to find a good smart pointer for navigation, and most of my pointers are for navigation.  (And of course, each pointer does have limited scope,  Pointers at namespace scope are rare.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Do you have some small example code perhaps? I'm curious... I am thinking reference wrappers or weak pointers, but it all depends on ownership and lifetime of your observers I suppose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first, and most important thing, is to never leave a pointer
uninitialized.  At the very least, set it to `nullptr` (or `NULL` in
pre-C++11) in the constructor, so you can at least test it for validity
later.

Beyond that, a lot depends on what it should point to:

- If the lifetime of what it points to is guaranteed to extend beyond
  the lifetime of your object (in both directions: it exists before your
  object is constructed, and will continue to exist after your object is
  destructed), pass it as a reference to the constructor, and take the
  address of the reference to initialize the pointer.
- If the lifetime of what it points to may not start until after your
  object is constructed, then you must set your pointer to null in the
  constructor, assign to it in the `setA` function, and verify that it is
  not null every time you want to use it.
- If the lifetime of what it points to may end before your object is
  destructed, then you need some sort of variant of the observer pattern,
  to notify your object that the pointed to object has been destructed,
  and set the pointer to null.  In this case, you'll also have to check
  for null every time before use.  In the past, I've used a `ManagedPtr`
  for this, but it's not a universal solution.  (It will null the pointer,
  but if the pointer is in a map or something, which is typically the
  case, it won't remove the entry from the map.)
- If the lifetime of your object should affect the lifetime of the
  pointed to object, then you should look into using `std::shared_ptr`.
  I've found such cases to be very rare in actual code, but they do occur.
  (Note that if you do use `std::shared_ptr`, you have to be very, very
  careful.  You can only construct one `std::shared_ptr` from any given
  raw pointer without running into problems.  In our own code base, we've
  banned `std::shared_ptr`, and use our own invasive reference counted
  pointer, in order to avoid such problems.  `std::shared_ptr` has been
  carefully designed to maximize the risk of dangling pointers and
  multiple deletes of the same object.)

Comment: Hm, I think the "always initialize a pointer" is a bit of a red herring. The fundamental problem remains that you need to communicate the nature of the pointee separately. Once you solve that problem, in my view, the initialization is secondary. It's more of an implementation detail: "This pointer will point to a dynamically allocated object or be null." But it's the lesser of two problems.

Comment: @KerrekSB It may be an implementation detail, but if you fail to do it, you cannot reliably test for raw pointers.  And of course, before you write the first line of code, you have to know what the code is supposed to do, and why it needs to know about the other object.  In most of the applications I've worked on in the past (large scale servers, mostly, but also a GUI front end), most pointers were simply for navigation: the observed in the observer pattern, for example, needs pointers to the observer.  None of the smart pointers I know handle this correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to avoid pointers in the first place. If you have to use pointers, consider using smart pointers such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). And always, *always* initialize the pointers, either to null (unless you use smart pointers) or to something you've allocated. And always *always* **always** check for null before using them.

Comment: That doesn't seem to address his problem at all.  First, there's not the slightest indication from his question that the object should in any way "own" the pointer; most of the time, pointers in objects are used for navigation.  And his real problem seems to be trying to use the pointer before it has been set.  (Admittedly, a smart pointer would be useful there, since it would guarantee a null pointer, which he could presumable test.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, I only said that the OP might want to *consider* using smart pointers. :)

Comment: It is, of course, one possibility.  Ideally, _all_ pointers would be more or less smart, if only to ensure initialization.  But not necessarily with the semantics of the smart pointers we have in the standard.  (And enforcing the discipline to _never_ not initialize a pointer, and to always check for null, isn't that hard.)

Answer (score 1):

> *"I usually forget to setA and bugs are introduced."*

So force yourself to set it by constructors:

```
struct B
{
    public:
      B(A *a) : ma(a) {}

    private:    
      A *mA;
};
```

And let `foo` check it:

```
foo()
{
  if (mA)
    mA->foo();
  else
    // handle it, throw exception, ignore, ...!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reference as a first choice if A object is always initialzied before `B` object:

```
struct B
{
    B(A& a) : mA(a) {}    
    foo() { mA.foo(); }    
    A& mA;
};

A a;
B b(a);
```